# How to get rid of Android Verification Errors

Tags: android

I'm using this method to get an array of BroadCast addresses.

Some of the methods and Classes used are not present in the old API
So i have added a version check at the beginning of the method.I'm trying to run this on a Android 1.6 Emulator and it fails with verify errors.

```
private InetAddress[] getBroadCast() throws SocketException
{

    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion < 9)
    {       
        try {
            String ipString = getWifiIp();
            int loc = ipString.lastIndexOf(".");
            InetAddress baddrs[] = new InetAddress[1];
            baddrs[0] = new InetAddress.getByName(ipString.substring(0, loc)+".255");
            return baddrs;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
            else{
    String bcast="";
    for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
        NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();

        for (InterfaceAddress address : intf.getInterfaceAddresses()) {
            if(address.getBroadcast()!=null) bcast=bcast+address.getBroadcast().toString().substring(1)+"::";
        }}
    String[] bcastarray= bcast.split("::");
    InetAddress baddrs[] = new InetAddress[bcastarray.length];
    for(int i=0;i<bcastarray.length;i++)
        try {
            baddrs[i] = new  InetAddress.getByName(bcastarray[i]);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return baddrs;
}
 }
```

These are the errors that come up

```
10-12 11:38:22.030: W/dalvikvm(297): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4463: Ljava/net/NetworkInterface;.getInterfaceAddresses ()Ljava/util/List;
10-12 11:38:22.030: W/dalvikvm(297): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6e at 0x0071
10-12 11:38:22.040: W/dalvikvm(297): VFY:  rejected Lhello/BroadcastSend;.getBroadCast ()[Lhello/IPMAddress;
10-12 11:38:22.040: W/dalvikvm(297): Verifier rejected class Lhello/BroadcastSend;
10-12 11:38:22.040: W/dalvikvm(297): threadid=19: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
```

android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is available only from API Level 4 and up. I'm looking for a workaround for these issues

Comment: Are you missing an `else` clause? With your current code the `getInterfaceAddresses()` code is executed regardless of version.

Comment: added the else clause, but that doesn't prevent the verifier from rejecting the code on a 1.6 device.

Comment: Ah, I see now. This won't work on 1.6. The 1.6 classloader will try to   check all methods, even if you don't actually call them, that is why you get the error. You have to make a wrapper class that calls `getInterfaceAddress()`, so that it doesn't get loaded at all.

Comment: I was trying to use Reflection to invoke the methods, but Wrapper Class seems to be easier and better :-) Please answer the question so that I can accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work on 1.6. The 1.6 classloader will try to check all methods, even if you don't actually call them, that is why you get the error. You have to make a wrapper class that calls `getInterfaceAddress()`, so that it doesn't get loaded at all.

Comment: thanks. I was using the multiple apk feature of Play Store to get rid of this. Now I'm using a single apk with wrapper classes :-) There was a pretty neat example at http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/backward-compatibility-for-android.html